# Powershell Append text to object description in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, powershell

How can I append or prepend the description in AD I want to leave the current description and put some text infront of it

for example a computer has the description as "Accounting Dept" (without quotes)

I tried this:

```
set-QADComputer -Identity computername
    -Description {Disabled 8/17/2012, Termrpt "$($_.description)"}
```

I get this for the description

> Disabled 8/17/2012, "$($_.description)"

but I want the orginal description prepended by the text like the following

> Disabled 8/17/2012, Accounting dept

any ideas?

I tried parentheses instead but then it just puts the prepended text and wipes out the original altogether.

Answer (score 4):

I don't use the QWEST AD cmdlets, so I don't know the exact syntax, but generally the best way is to retrieve the current description, save it to a variable, and then just write $Current_Desc + $addendum back to the object.

Answer (score 4):

I don't use the Qwest modules. If you're willing to use the Microsoft AD module, included with RSAT, the following is pretty straightforward.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Let's check the Description
Get-ADUser jscott -Properties Description |
  Select-Object -Property Description

Description
-----------
Junior Keyboard MRO Tech

# Cool, set it the new value
Get-ADUser jscott -Properties Description |
  ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADUser $_ -Description "Disabled 8/17/2012, Termrpt $($_.Description)"
  }

# Let's check the new Description
Get-ADUser jscott -Properties Description |
  Select-Object -Property Description

Description
-----------
Disabled 8/17/2012, Termrpt Disabled Junior Keyboard MRO Tech
```

I think what's tripping you up is the usage of `$_` as parameter of a cmdlet, rather than within a script block.  I've wrapped `Set-ADUser` in a `ForEach_Object`, ensuring `$_` is the object from the pipeline.  Outside of a script block, as in your case, using `$_` as a parameter will return `$null`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to MDMarra's answer (beat me to the punch), you can also set a string variable to be equal to an appended value with `+=`, so something like `$Description += "blah"` would append "blah" to the end of your variable value.

(`$Description += "blah"` being short hand for `$Description = $Description + "blah"`)